# Add compile option if shared lib is linked

Tags: gcc, cmake, vxworks

I have a special compiler that need an extra flag `-non-static` when linking an executable to with an shared lib:

`gcc main.cpp -non-static -lshared  -o main`

(Note: Its the compiler for vxworks)

How can i do this in CMake?

Solutions i have used so far (but are not satisfying):

1. Always set `-non-static` in the toolchain file. Works, but has unwanted side effects when you dont need any shared lib.

   ```
   set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} "-non-static")
   ```
2. Create a `INTERFACE` library with `-non-static` compile option set.    However, each new project must rewrite this and and each executable must link this library (if it links any shared lib):

   ```
   add_library(allwaysLinkMe INTERFACE)
   if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUALS "VxWorks")
      target_link_libraries(allwaysLinkMe INTERFACE "-non-static")
   endif()

   add_library(shared SHARED a.cpp)
   add_executatble(main main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(main shared allwaysLinkMe)
   ```

   Or i link this library to all other shared libraries:

   ```
   add_library(shared SHARED a.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(shared allwaysLinkMe) 
   add_executatble(main main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(main shared)
   ```

   In both cases, I must use ifs to prevent this from failing with other target platforms. Also both are pretty ugly and error prone.

I am looking for a solution, that is only in the toolchain/platform/compiler file(s) and no change to the project must be made.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Why not have 2 different configurations for these 2 cases? It will save you the trouble of adding and removing the library aswell.

Comment: @Emut What do you mean with configuration? Its usally lile "Debug" or "Release" and i cannot see the connection to different flags.